# JavaFX Show options around a node

Tags: javafx, contextmenu

i was trying to implement a custom context menu that the menu items will appear around the node, the idea was as follows, draw a virtual circle around the target node, and compute the circumference of the circle, first menu item will be at the top of the target node, and the rest will be distributed with equal distance between each one of the menu items,,,, i didnt write any line of code because i dont know how to start at least,,, plz help ?

maybe this image will explain better

[image]

Comment: [Google javafx radial menu](https://www.google.com/?q=javafx+radial+menu&gws_rd=ssl#)

Comment: So you've got [polar coordinates and want to convert to Cartesian coordinates?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: @fabian i think i can start coding now ,,, http://www.ajdesigner.com/phpcircle/circle_arc_length_theta.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone is interested, i manged to do it , but the code is kinda dirty:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

/**
     * @author Asendar
 *
 */
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class RadialMenuFactory {
    public static final RadialMenuFactory instance = new RadialMenuFactory();

    public StackPane construct(int itemsCount, int radius) {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();

        double pheta = 270;

        int counter = 0;

        while (counter != itemsCount) {
            double x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pheta));
            double y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pheta));

            Button btn = new Button("btn");

            btn.setTranslateX(x);
            btn.setTranslateY(y);

            pane.getChildren().addAll(btn);

            pheta += 360 / itemsCount;
            pheta %= 360;

            counter++;
        }

        pane.setMinHeight(300);
        pane.setMinWidth(300);

        return pane;
    }

}
```